Using STT model in local GPU computer with executing time too long
I use the below script to Speech To Text in google colab, running time around 5min for the uploaded record
    model_dir = drive_path
# Initialize the pipeline
pipe = pipeline("automatic-speech-recognition", 
                model=WhisperForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_dir), 
                tokenizer= WhisperTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_dir),
                feature_extractor = WhisperFeatureExtractor.from_pretrained(model_dir),
                chunk_length_s=5,
)

def transcribe(audio):
    text = pipe(audio)["text"]
    return text

audio_path = google_drive_audio_path
print(transcribe(audio_path))

With the same code, I use in my computer, it just printted out the last content in the audio and the running time is 7min.
I tried to chunk it, but I had to wait 30 minutes without any result, just print out blank space
def process_chunk(chunk):
    # Convert pydub AudioSegment to numpy array
    samples = np.array(chunk.get_array_of_samples(), dtype=np.float32)
    # Normalize audio
    samples = samples / np.iinfo(chunk.array_type).max
    print(pipe(samples)['text'])
    return pipe(samples)["text"]

def transcribe(audio_path):
    # Split audio into chunks
    audio = AudioSegment.from_file(audio_path)
    chunk_length_ms = 5000  # 5 seconds in milliseconds
    chunks = make_chunks(audio, chunk_length_ms)
    
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        # Process chunks in parallel
        results = list(executor.map(process_chunk, chunks))
    
    # Concatenate all the text from the chunks
    text = " ".join(results)
    return text

my computer doesnt have GPU, I just use CPU, but google colab I just use CPU too.
My question:

How can I change my code to get the whole content?
Why running code in google colab can get the whole content without any chunk size, but the code when running in local just get the last line?

Because my audio has personal information, I cannot upload it to google drive
